# Parse error. missing name after . operator

Tags: javascript

I have the following code where I am using **VAST player** to play my ads.
I am using a check to see if the user has clicked already to avoid the DOM exception that is present in modern browsers.

```
(function(VASTPlayer) {
    'use strict';

    var player = new VASTPlayer(document.getElementById(playerID));

    player.once('AdStopped', function() {
        console.log('Ad finished playback! ' + playerID);
        interstitialInstance.close();
    });

    player.load( << Ad Tag >> ).then(function startAd() {
        console.log(player.adDuration + " " + playerID);

        var s = document.getElementById(playerID).childNodes[0];
        if (s) {
            if (!ryads.mouseClick) {
                s.muted = true;
            } else
                s.muted = false;
        } else {
            console.log("Error while fetching video element!!!");
        }

        return player.startAd();
    }).catch(function(reason) {
        console.log('Ad failed to play ' + playerID);
        interstitialInstance.close();
        setTimeout(function() {
            throw reason;
        }, 0);
    });
}(window.VASTPlayer));
```

I am getting the following error when I run the Compress job in Jenkins.

> project.js:891: ERROR - Parse error. missing name after . operator
>               }).catch(function(reason) {
>                        ^
>
> project.js:892: ERROR - Parse error. syntax error
>                   console.log('Ad failed to play '+playerID);
>                            ^
>
> project.js:896: ERROR - Parse error. missing ; before statement
>       }(window.VASTPlayer));

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis. Change it to  })(window.VASTPlayer));

Comment: @Barmar why did you just fix the code by editing?

Comment: @Esko I just fixed the indentation so it was readable.

Comment: @Barmar You added the wrapping function? First line.

Comment: Is it all? Looks like some part of the code at the beginning is omitted. Also what is <<Ad Tag>>? It's not a valid JavaScript

Comment: That was already there, just not visible due to StackoverFlow Editor limitations.

Comment: Ok then, confusing that is not visible in the edit comparison either...

Comment: @Esko - Yes, I added the wrapping function.

`
function ShowVastPlayer(interstitialInstance){
    var playerID = interstitialInstance.params.placeguid;
(function(VASTPlayer).....
`

Answer (score 3):

This is a well known issue [**since years**](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/203) for yuicompressor.
An easy fix for is to extract the resolve and reject functions of the promise like this:

```js
promise.then(successFunction, failureFunction);

function successFunction() {
   console.log('success');
}

function failureFunction(err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
(function(VASTPlayer) {
```

by

```
;(function(VASTPlayer) {
```

Otherwise, when the compression job is trying to concatenate files, your IIFE might be considered an argument to the code that the end of the file contained which was concatenated right before this file.

Can you please elaborate on what

```
player.load( << Ad Tag >>
```

is? That is not valid Javascript. Some sort of JSX dialect? Or just a copy/paste error?

Comment: I don't think there's a missing `)`. The second `)` in `))` matches the `(` on the first line.

Comment: @Barmar I just saw it was not even your comment, lol. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: player.load actually loads the Ad for playing. The tag is the value provided for the Ad.

Comment: @yogeshsriraman Again, that is not valid Javascript. What language is that? JSX? I'm referring to the `<< Ad Tag >>` part.

Comment: @connexo - these are nodeJS

Comment: nodeJS **is** Javascript, and also there `<< Ad Tag >>` is not valid Javascript.

Comment: I have just mentioned as "<<Ad Tag>>". It is actually a string. A URL to be precise. IT returns a list of Ad providers that is supported. Then an Ad is taken from that and played.